# Как импортировать большие файлы xlsx частями?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Здравствуйте есть код который импортуирет файлы xlsx в базу MySQL.

```
<?php

session_save_path(dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']).'/public_html/tmp');

ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
set_time_limit('0');




require_once __DIR__ . "/../../vendor/autoload.php";
require_once __DIR__ . "/../../component/Db.php";

$db = Db::connectDB();


$file_url         = "/admin/files/prices/prices_1529587320.xlsx";
$what_row = "2";
$col_article      = "2";
$col_articleSearch     = "0";
$brand            = "Volkswagen";
$col_description        = "3";
$col_group_price        = "5";
$col_price       = "4";
$col_min_value        = "6";
$col_exchange        = "7";
$date             = "2018-01-04";


// чистим на пустоту
foreach(['file_url', 'what_row', 'col_article', 'col_articleSearch', 'brand', 'col_description', 'col_group_price', 'col_price', 'col_min_value', 'col_exchange', 'date'] as $field) {
  $$field = trim($$field);
}

// переводим в INT
foreach(['what_row', 'col_article', 'col_description', 'col_group_price', 'col_price', 'col_min_value', 'col_exchange'] as $field) {
  $$field = (int) $$field;
  if($$field === 0) $$field = '';
}


$filePath = realpath(__DIR__ . "/../../" . $file_url);

$row = $what_row;

/*
* Обновляем статус всех прайсов на old
*/
$sql = "UPDATE `dk_prices` SET status = 'old', price = '0' WHERE brand = '$brand'";
$db->query($sql);


$reader = PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::load($filePath);


foreach ($reader->getWorksheetIterator() as $line) {
  $highestRow = $line->getHighestRow();
  for($row; $row <= $highestRow; $row++) {

    $article = $line->getCellByColumnAndRow( $col_article, $row )->getValue();
    if($col_articleSearch == "0") {
      $searchArticle = str_replace(' ', '', $article);
    } else {
      $searchArticle = $line->getCellByColumnAndRow( $col_articleSearch, $row )->getValue();
    }
    $description   = $line->getCellByColumnAndRow( $col_description, $row )->getValue();
    $group_price   = $line->getCellByColumnAndRow( $col_group_price, $row )->getValue();
    $price   = $line->getCellByColumnAndRow( $col_price, $row )->getValue();
    $min_value   = $line->getCellByColumnAndRow( $col_min_value , $row )->getValue();
    $exchange   = $line->getCellByColumnAndRow( $col_exchange, $row )->getValue();


    // проверяем на пустоту
    foreach(['article', 'searchArticle', 'brand', 'description', 'group_price', 'price', 'min_value', 'exchange'] as $field) {
      if(is_null( $$field )) {
        $$field = "";
      }
    }

    /*
     * Если такой артикул и бренд существует, то обновляем данные
     */

    $sql = "SELECT searchArticle and brand from `dk_prices` where searchArticle = ?s and brand = ?s";
    $result = $db->query($sql, $searchArticle, $brand);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
      $sql = "UPDATE `dk_prices` SET ?u WHERE searchArticle = ?s and brand = ?s";
      $user_data   = array(
        'description'             => $description,
        'group_price'             => $group_price,
        'price'             => $price,
        'exchange'          => $exchange,
        'min_value'         => $min_value,
        'date'              => $date,
        'status'            => 'update'
      );
      $db->query($sql, $user_data, $searchArticle, $brand);
    } else {
      /*
       * Если такого бренда и артикула нету, то добавляем нововую строку
       */
      $sql         = "INSERT INTO `dk_prices` SET ?u";
      $user_data   = array(
        'article'           => $article,
        'searchArticle'     => $searchArticle,
        'brand'             => $brand,
        'description'             => $description,
        'group_price'             => $group_price,
        'price'             => $price,
        'exchange'          => $exchange,
        'min_value'         => $min_value,
        'date'              => $date,
        'status'            => 'new'
      );
      $db->query($sql, $user_data);
    }
  }
}
```

Но когда файл большой около 60мб тоесть с сотнями тысяч строк, то этот код долго думает а потом пишет Killed, писал в сапорт сказали что он занимает много места.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На сайте бибилотеки [здесь](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/topics/reading-files/) есть код для загрузки по частям

```
$inputFileType = 'Xls';
$inputFileName = './sampleData/example2.xls';

/**  Define a Read Filter class implementing \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\IReadFilter  */
class ChunkReadFilter implements \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\IReadFilter
{
    private $startRow = 0;
    private $endRow   = 0;

    /**  Set the list of rows that we want to read  */
    public function setRows($startRow, $chunkSize) {
        $this->startRow = $startRow;
        $this->endRow   = $startRow + $chunkSize;
    }

    public function readCell($column, $row, $worksheetName = '') {
        //  Only read the heading row, and the configured rows
        if (($row == 1) || ($row >= $this->startRow && $row < $this->endRow)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

/**  Create a new Reader of the type defined in $inputFileType  **/
$reader = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);

/**  Define how many rows we want to read for each "chunk"  **/
$chunkSize = 2048;
/**  Create a new Instance of our Read Filter  **/
$chunkFilter = new ChunkReadFilter();

/**  Tell the Reader that we want to use the Read Filter  **/
$reader->setReadFilter($chunkFilter);

/**  Loop to read our worksheet in "chunk size" blocks  **/
for ($startRow = 2; $startRow <= 65536; $startRow += $chunkSize) {
    /**  Tell the Read Filter which rows we want this iteration  **/
    $chunkFilter->setRows($startRow,$chunkSize);
    /**  Load only the rows that match our filter  **/
    $spreadsheet = $reader->load($inputFileName);
    //    Do some processing here
}
```

Вопрос как этот класс по частям внедрить в мой код ?

p.s. Писать про wait_timeout не надо, у меня и так стоит 900, суть в оптимизации памяти.

Вспомнил что я убирал код связаный с инсертом и апдейтом, 
тоесть после этого:

```
$reader = PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::load($filePath);
```

скрипт сразу падал, нужно как-то внедрить этот класс, а не игратся с базой.

Comment: с формулами? экспортировать бы вам чисто данные в xml-какой и оттуда влить.

Comment: там без формул, чисто данные. У меня тут в коде реализована возможность выбора номера колонок, можно такое в xml ?

Comment: в таких объемах проще юзать стандартный импорт в базу, если есть возможность. из csv например. сначала влить все во временную таблицу, потом перелить куда надо с апдейтами и т.п.
про XML упомянул т.к. там там помимо DOM моделей есть SAX-парсеры, которые не едят память. Либо пробовать другие библиотеки, если уверены в корректности вашего кода.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/box/spout вот правильная библиотека, жрет мегабайта 2 независимо от размера файла

```
use Box\Spout\Reader\ReaderFactory;
use Box\Spout\Common\Type;

$reader = ReaderFactory::create(Type::XLSX); // for XLSX files
//$reader = ReaderFactory::create(Type::CSV); // for CSV files
//$reader = ReaderFactory::create(Type::ODS); // for ODS files

$reader->open($filePath);

$line = 0;
foreach ($reader->getSheetIterator() as $sheet) {
    foreach ($sheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
        $line++;
        if($line <= $what_row - 1) {
            continue;
        } else {
            $article = $row[$col_article - 1];
            if($col_articleSearch == "0") {
                $searchArticle = str_replace(' ', '', $article);
            } else {
                $searchArticle = $row[$col_articleSearch - 1];
            }
            if($brand_check == "brand_col") {
                $brandText = $row[(int)$brand - 1];
            } else {
                $brandText = $brand;
            }
            $description   = $row[$col_description - 1];
            $images   = $row[$col_images - 1];
            $delivery   = $row[$col_delivery - 1];
            $active   = $row[$col_active - 1];
            $category   = $row[$col_category - 1];
            $barcode   = $row[$col_barcode - 1];
            $weight = $row[$col_weight - 1];
            $comment = $row[$col_comment - 1];

            // проверяем на пустоту
            foreach(['article', 'searchArticle', 'brandText', 'description', 'images', 'delivery', 'active', 'category', 'barcode', 'weight', 'comment'] as $field) {
                if(is_null( $$field )) {
                    $$field = "";
                }
                if($$field == -1) {
                    $$field = "";
                }
            }

            if($delivery !== "") {
                $delivery = "Не поставлается";
            }
            if($active !== "") {
                $active = "Не активный";
                $view = "hidden";
            } else {
                $view = "visible";
            }

            //Если такой артикул и бренд существует, то обновляем данные
            $sql = "SELECT searchArticle and brand from `dk_products` where searchArticle = ?s and brand = ?s";
            $result = $db->query($sql, $searchArticle, $brandText);
            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                $sql = "UPDATE `dk_products` SET ?u where searchArticle = ?s and brand = ?s";
                $user_data   = array(
                    'description'      => $description,
                    'images'      => $images,
                    'delivery'      => $delivery,
                    'active'      => $active,
                    'category'      => $category,
                    'barcode'      => $barcode,
                    'weight'    => $weight,
                    'comment'    => $comment,
                    'view'    => $view,
                );
                $db->query($sql, $user_data, $searchArticle, $brandText);
            } else {
                //Если такого бренда и артикула нету, то добавляем нововую строку
                $sql         = "INSERT INTO `dk_products` SET ?u";
                $user_data   = array(
                    'article'           => $article,
                    'searchArticle'     => $searchArticle,
                    'brand'             => $brandText,
                    'description'              => $description,
                    'images'      => $images,
                    'delivery'      => $delivery,
                    'active'      => $active,
                    'category'      => $category,
                    'barcode'      => $barcode,
                    'weight'    => $weight,
                    'comment'    => $comment,
                    'view'    => $view,
                );
                $db->query($sql, $user_data);
            }
            $db->free($result);
        }
    }
}

$reader->close();
```